# File object in WinJS - how to retrieve the containing folder

Tags: windows-8, winjs, file-access

I have got a app with the `getItemsAsync()`-method returning a file-object for a picture chosen by the user with a file picker. Now I would like to get the folder-object of the folder which contains the image to make the user able to switch between the pictures in that folder without using the filepicker again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is available upon return from the file picker. See:

[Docs for StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile)

You can in turn then call

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.getFolderFromPathAsync(path)
                             .done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );
```

to get you the StorageFolder from that path.

[Docs for GetFolderFromPathAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync)

Answer (score 1):

if the app likely want to 'access' any file in the select folder, using [FolderPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) is probably right. otherwise, the app will likely not have access to all files in the folder.

Comment: +1 - if the user picks a single file with the FileOpenPicker, only this file will be available to the app. If you want to access another file, you'll have to ask the user to pick it separately or use a folder picker. And don't forget to store access tokens where applicable...